# Stop script execution while jquery animation runs

Tags: jquery, animation

Is there any way to freeze any jquery script functions while animation runs?

for example:

```
$('#some_div').append('some stuff');
$('some_another_tag').remove();
$('#modal_window').fadeIn(300);
```

etc etc, is there any way to process all that stuf in threads?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to pause execution, but you can give fadeIn() a callback that'll run when the animation is complete:

```
$('#modal_window').fadeIn(300);
stuffToDoAfterFade();
```

becomes

```
$('#modal_window').fadeIn(300, function() {
    stuffToDoAfterFade();
});
```